# Has Telegram API any restriction for send messages?

Tags: telegram

I'm using Telegram API to send message on behalf of my self.

Has Telegram any restriction on the messages per second that I can send via a client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general i think you will get a flood_wait error if you send to fast.

For Bots, there is a hard limit of 30 messages/second and 1 message per second to each user (you can find that in their docs)

As per the core API, I would say possibly stick  to the BOT limits, but your best bet would be to TEST, and see @ what point you start getting FLOOD_WAIT errors